# killing or closing a process

Tags: c#, process

I want to know how to close or kill a process (xyz.exe),when it occupies the
memory even after closing it or killing it through task manager.

from another c# appln

is there any other way to stop the process which hangs in memory,i desperately need to
know how to do it.

is it possible to write a kernel level program and try killing the process?

is there any tool available for doing this process?

unable to kill the process using `process.kill()`, process got hanged, is it possible to
kill it by some other way?

Comment: From C# or just using a tool?

Comment: If Process.Kill doesn't kill the process, then why is this? Have you figured that out?

Answer (score 3):

[ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can kill everything, but I think the authors actually had to write a new kernel diver to implement it (I am not sure though)

Comment: No, Process Explorer does not use its driver to terminate processes.

Answer (score 2):

If you've killed it through task-manager, it should be dead. If it refuses to close via task-manager (and you are an admin), you'll struggle to do any better through code. However, you can get the `Process` object (perhaps by `Process.GetProcessesByName(...)`) and `.Kill()` it. I wouldn't expect it to do any better than task-man, though.